# Cannot explode a nested JSON within spark dataframe

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I am new to Spark. I am trying to flatten a dataframe but failed to do so with "explode".

The original dataframe schema is like below:

```
ID|ApprovalJSON
1|[{"ApproverType":"1st Line Manager","Status":"Approved"},{"ApproverType":"2nd Line Manager","Status":"Approved"}]
2|[{"ApproverType":"1st Line Manager","Status":"Approved"},{"ApproverType":"2nd Line Manager","Status":"Rejected"}]
```

I need to convert it to below schema?

```
ID|ApprovalType|Status
1|1st Line Manager|Approved
1|2nd Line Manager|Approved
2|1st Line Manager|Approved
2|2nd Line Manager|Rejected
```

I have tried

```
df_exploded = df.withColumn("ApprovalJSON", explode("ApprovalJSON"))
```

But I got error:

> Cannot resolve "explode(ApprovalJSON)" due to data type mismatch:
> parameter 1 requires ("ARRAY" or "MAP") type, however, "ApprovalJSON"
> is of "STRING" type.;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parse the JSON like strings to array of structs then use `inline` to explode array into rows and columns

```
df1 = df.withColumn("ApprovalJSON", F.from_json("ApprovalJSON", schema="array<struct<ApproverType string, Status string>>"))
df1 = df1.select("ID", F.inline('ApprovalJSON'))
```

Result

```
df1.show()

+---+----------------+--------+
| ID|    ApproverType|  Status|
+---+----------------+--------+
|  1|1st Line Manager|Approved|
|  1|2nd Line Manager|Approved|
|  2|1st Line Manager|Approved|
|  2|2nd Line Manager|Rejected|
+---+----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Is F. come from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Comment: thats correct..

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your code is working well. But indeed my table there are 2 columns with the JSON structure. When I run df1 = df1.select("ID", F.inline('ApprovalJSON'), F.inline('ApprovalJSON2')) I was prompted for error: "The generator is not supported: only one generator allowed per SELECT clause but found 2"

Comment: Can you please post another question with the new scenario and expected output and perhaps mark this question as complete?